# GWT Propagate Event on views in activities

Tags: gwt

How to throw a View event, such click on a button, in view's activity? View doesn't know activity eventBus..
I miss something? I'm using 2.3 sdk

Comment: Some code examples would help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to keep a reference to the Activity in the view and then forward the event to the Activity, which can then use the EventBus in it's own method.

There is a small example on this page:
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

But basically, I usually use @UiHandler to handle the ClickEvent, and then invoke a method in the Activity. In the Activity I then perform the action that uses the EventBus, RPC, or so. I know some people prefer handling the event directly in the Activity but to me this seems like a nicer separation of concern and keeps the View nicely "stupid".

An example:

Button says something like "Select active customer"

View handles ClickEvent for the button, invokes presenter.customerSelected(...)

Activity has customerSelected method and creates a ActiveCustomerSelectedEvent, which is sends on the EventBus.